# counting with max and min restrictions

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 10$$
But $x_1 \ge 1$ and $x_2 \ge2$.

Finally, $x_1<6,  x_2<6, x_3<6$ and $x_4<6$.

I started off by finding the total amount that you can get for the original equation. That would be $C (13, 3)$. Then i calculated for the cases of numbers being greater than or equal to 5. I dont know how to incorporate $x_1\ge1$ and $x_2\ge2$. Any help?

$x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$ are all integers that could be >= 0(But $x_1$ and $x_2$ have their own restriction).

Comment: are $$x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$$ assumed to be integers?

Comment: Yes, my mistake

Comment: If $6x_2 < 6$, then $x_2 < 1$.  In combination with $x_2 \ge 2$, there are no solutions.

Comment: typo again, sorry. COuld anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

We wish to find the number of nonnegative integer solutions of the equation 
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 10 \tag{1}$$
subject to the restrictions $1 \leq x_1 \leq 5$, $2 \leq x_2 \leq 5$, $x_3 \leq 5$, and $x_4 \leq 5$.

Let $y_1 = x_1 - 1$ and $y_2 = x_2 - 2$.  Then $y_1$ and $y_2$ are nonnegative integers satisfying the inequalities $y_1 \leq 4$ and $y_2 \leq 3$.  Substituting $y_1 + 1$ for $x_1$ and $y_2 + 2$ for $x_2$ in equation 1 yields 
\begin{align*}
y_1 + 1 + y_2 + 2 + x_3 + x_4 & = 10\\
y_1 + y_2 + x_3 + x_4 & = 7 \tag{2}
\end{align*}
Equation 2 is an equation in the nonnegative integers subject to the restrictions that $y_1 \leq 4$, $y_2 \leq 3$, $x_3 \leq 5$, $x_4 \leq 5$.

If we ignore those restrictions for the moment, we need to determine the number of solutions of equation 2 in the nonnegative integers.  A particular solution corresponds to the placement of three addition signs in a row of seven ones.  For instance, 
$$+ 1 1 + 1 1 1 1 + 1$$
corresponds to the solution $y_1 = 0$, $y_2 = 2$, $x_3 = 4$, $x_4 = 1$.  The number of such solutions is 
$$\binom{7 + 3}{3} = \binom{10}{3}$$
since we must choose which three of the ten positions required for seven ones and three addition signs will be filled with addition signs.

From these, we must exclude those cases which violate one or more of the restrictions.  Notice that it is not possible to violate two of the conditions simultaneously since $5 + 4 = 9 > 7$.

Let's consider the restriction $y_1 \leq 4$.  Suppose $y_1 \geq 5$.  Let $z_1 = y_1 - 5$.  Then $z_1$ is a nonnegative integer.  Substituting $z_1 + 5$ for $y_1$ in equation 2 yields
\begin{align*}
z_1 + 5 + y_2 + x_3 + x_4 & = 7\\
z_1 + y_2 + x_3 + x_4 & = 2 \tag{3}
\end{align*}
Equation 3 is an equation in the nonnegative integers with 
$$\binom{2 + 3}{3} = \binom{5}{3}$$
solutions.  Hence, the number of solutions of equation 2 that violate the restriction $y_1 \leq 4$ (and $x_1 \leq 5$ in equation 1) is $\binom{5}{3}$.

To complete the problem, you must subtract the number of cases in which the restrictions $y_1 \leq 4$, $y_2 \leq 3$, $x_3 \leq 5$, or $x_4 \leq 5$ are violated from the number of unrestricted solutions of equation 2.

Can you continue?

Answer (score 0):

- For your first condition: let's denote $f(x)$ the cardinal number of the set of integers x subject to some condition.

As known that the first $f(x_1\ge1)=|\{1...10\}|=10$ , $x_2$ is bound by $2$ and $10-x_1$ which denotes $f(x_2\ge2)=10-x_1-2$ this quantity can be valid only if $x_1\le8$.

Since $x_2\ge2$ and $x_1\ge1$ then $x_3,x_4$ must be inferior or equal to $10-1-2$

This gives the system of inequations:

$$\begin{matrix}1\le x_1\le 8\end{matrix}$$
$$\begin{matrix}2\le x_2\le 9\end{matrix}$$
$$\begin{matrix}0\le x_3\le 7\end{matrix}$$
$$\begin{matrix}0\le x_4\le 7\end{matrix}$$

With the general condition $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=10$

Now you can just make use of [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) taking in count the 4 afromentioned conditions like this.

$*******|**|*$

$***|****|**|*$

or even

$*****|*****$

Pay attention that 1,2 or 3 bars can be used to patition the set of 10 stars, also pay attention to fold 2 or more stars always between two bars.

Another remark about permutations, It can only be for the first configuration of 2 bars where the offset remaining leftside the last bar can be assigned to either of $x_3$ or $x_4$ withe the other variable being annuled.

Last remark you can just avoid the case of less than 2 stars for $x_2$ by theory of exclusion: $S=S(all)-S(x_2<2)$. Another proposition too is to deal with two stars as one twofold such that:

$*******|٭|*$ for the first configuration,

$***|****|٭|*$ for the second.

This is sufficient for you to continue from !