# Repetition with restrictions

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Your local grocery store just received a large shipment of apples,
oranges, pears, and bananas---there are only 5 of each fruit.  You are
shopping at the store and will purchase your fruit for the week.

How many ways can you select $10$ pieces of fruit from your store's
supply of apples, oranges, pears, and bananas, if you need at least
$2$ oranges and $1$ apple?

I understand that there are 17 spots to choose from because 3 have been chosen and there are a total of 20 fruits. Would I use the combination by repetition formula? I can't quite wrap my head around what to do. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes.  You need to solve the equation $a + b + o + p = 7$ subject to the restrictions that $a \leq 4$, $b \leq 5$, $o \leq 3$, and $p \leq 5$.

Comment: In the case of the combination formula (17 + r -1 choose 17). What would my r be?

Comment: Why are you using $17$?  You are only selecting an additional $7$ pieces of fruit.  Please see my answer to [this version](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2537542/counting-with-max-and-min-restrictions/2538609#2538609) of the question you posed.

Comment: I looked over your solution. I see you approached it using the stars and bars method. How would I represent a <= 4 in terms of y? y = a+4?

Comment: If there were no restrictions, the number of solutions would be $\binom{7 + 3}{3} = \binom{10}{3}$.  From there, we must address the restrictions.  Suppose $a > 4$.  Then $a' = a - 5$ is a nonnegative integer.  Substituting $a' + 5$ for $a$ in the equation $a + b + o + p = 7$ yields $a' + b + o + p = 2$, so $\binom{2 + 3}{3} = \binom{5}{3}$ solutions violate the restriction $a \leq 4$.

Comment: So how would I go about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As N. F. Taussig stated in the comments above, you need to solve for how many solutions (among non negative integers) has the equation:

$$\tag{I}a+o+p+b=7$$ with restrictions $a\le4, o\le3, p\le5, b\le5$

If there were **no** restrictions, then the equation (I) has ${{7+4-1}\choose{7}}=120$ non negative solutions.

But  you need to subtract those who "violate" the restrictions (separately):

**First ($a\le4$)**

If $a\ge5$, this violates the first restriction. Let $y=a-5\ge0$, the equation becomes:

$$y+o+p+b=2$$ which has ${{2+4-1}\choose{2}}=10$ non negative solutions

**Second ($o\le3$)**

$o\ge4$ violates the second restriction. Let $z=o-4\ge0$, the equation becomes:
$$a+z+p+b=3$$
which has ${{3+4-1}\choose{3}}=20$ non negative solutions

**Third ($p\le5$)**

$p\ge6$ violates the third restriction. Let $w=p-6\ge0$, the equation becomes:
$$a+o+w+b=1$$ which has ${{1+4-1}\choose{1}}=4$ non negative solutions

**Fourth ($b\le5$)**

Analogously to the previous one, there are ${{1+4-1}\choose{1}}=4$ solutions who violate the fourth restriction

In total we have $10+20+4+4=38$ solutions of equation (I) such that do not follow the restrictions. Therefore, there are $120-38=82$ solutions

Comment: Generally, this solution only works if it's not possible to violate two restrictions at the same time. Otherwise you would double-count some restrictions that were already accounted for by non negative solutions of a prior restriction.

Comment: [A link to a more general description to the approach](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/combinations-of-elements-in-multisets-with-finite-repetition)